# Where To set my connection string in WPF Core 3?

Tags: wpf, domain-driven-design, aspnetboilerplate, .net-core-3.0

I have a **DDD** project (aspnetboilerplate solution) , that i want to extend with WPF Core3.
I didn't find where to set my connection string in Wpf Core 3, there is no **appsetting.json** or **app.config** ?

Comment: Add an appsettings.json file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings

Answer (score 1):

well, just moved some settings from shared lib to wpf core app.
i did it this way
project - properties - resources - add resources
add name (for instance OurDb) , connection string

access it in code namespace.properties.resources.ourdb

in my case this is

```
var cstring = csAdmin.Properties.Resources.OurDb;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had the same question and I tied this and it works.
Add this to your DBContext and make sure that you use the correct database type in options builder

```
private string _connectionString = "conectionstring"

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
}
```

Comment: This hard codes the connection string, not what the OP was asking.